# Given an infinite set, can we give an infinite chain of finite subsets of that set, with the chain ordered by the proper subset operator?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'll explain why I think the answer is yes, and then why I'm not happy:

So we have set $S$, with infinite cardinality.  We take $X \subset S$ (with $X$ finite cardinality) as the starting point of our chain.  Now we take $s \in S$ such that $s \not\in X$ and create new set $X \cup s$, which is also finite.  We can repeat this operation infinitely (adding some $s \in S$ not currently in our set), so we have an infinite chain.

This can't work because then our set will tend towards infinite cardinality.  But the union of two finite sets is finite, so I don't see, if you were to set up a computer to do this, at what point the approach will break.

I know that my understanding of infinity is kind of weak, so if anyone can explain what's going on I'd be really grateful.

Comment: "This can't work because then our set will tend towards infinite cardinality." Can you elaborate what you mean by that and why it's a concern?

Comment: Don't you expect an infinite chain of proper subsets to tend to infinite cardinality?  How could its cardinality be bounded?

Comment: The sequence $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ _tends to_ infinity but each element of the sequence is finite. Your example is similar. Each set is finite, but their cardinalities tend toward infinity.

Comment: My concern is that if it tends to infinity and we're doing this infinitely many times, then it will end up infinite.  But we're only allowing finite subsets.

Comment: How do you know that it will "end up" at all?

Comment: Look at $\Bbb N$'s initial segments, $I_n=\{k\in\Bbb N\mid k<n\}$, then $\{I_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an example for a chain like that. Where do you find this problematic?

Comment: I suppose I don't.  It just breaks my intuition.  We have an infinite chain of sets strictly increasing as we go and none of them are infinite.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, but also none of them are "infinitely far down the line." It might be easier to think about numbers instead of sets: we have an infinite sequence of finite natural numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, ...$, none of which is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

> This can't work because then our set will tend towards infinite cardinality. But the union of two finite sets is finite

Your approach is essentially correct (to formalize it properly you may want to read about the axiom of choice). To address your concern: consider the sequence of sets

$$A_n = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$$

Each $A_n$ is finite and $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$, yet the union of all of them is the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, which is infinite. This is because the union of infinitely many finite sets can be infinite.

Comment: Sufficient to have the somewhat weaker [axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice).

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you for pointing this out =) In fact, even the weaker [ACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) is [enough here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_has_Countably_Infinite_Subset#Proof_4).

Comment: @GLG: In fact the even weaker "Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you =) [Further reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51415/is-it-possible-to-show-that-an-infinite-set-has-a-countable-infinite-subset-w) for the curious.

Comment: I should probably also mention about countable choice and infinite sets in this context, and that the proof itself suggested here (by the OP and you) *does* need, as currently formulated, Dependent Choice. One can avoid it by first limiting oneself to a countably infinite subset, but that's another step that needs to be explicitly mentioned in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the construction, but it includes a hidden assumption:   We can show that for every $n\in \Bbb N$ there exists a collection $$C(n)=\{X_j: 1\leq j\leq n+1\}$$ of subsets of $S,$ with $X_1=X$,  such that,for each $j\leq n$ we have $X_j\subset X_{j+1}\subset S,$ and such that $X_{j+1}$  \ $X_j$ has just $1$ member.

BUT this does not imply that there exists an infinite sequence $\{X_j:j\in \Bbb N\}.$  Students will often say "Why can't we  just take $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}C(n)$ ?". The answer is that there's no such thing as $\{C(n):n\in \Bbb N\}$ because for each $n$ there are many (infinitely many, in fact) possible sets that satisfy the conditions for $C(n)$. Also, if you choose one of them and call it $C'(n)$ there are infinitely many choices for $C'(n+1)=\{X_1,...,X_{n+2}\}$ such that $\{X_1,...,X_{n+1}\}=C'(n).$  There is no "operation" that tells you how to uniquely define $C'(n+1)$ from $C'(n).$

The solution is to apply the Axiom of Dependent Choice (DC), which is implied by the Axiom of Choice (AC). It has been shown that AC (and hence any of its implications) is relatively consistent with the other axioms of set theory (That is, if the rest of the axioms are consistent, we can consistently add AC to the axioms). Most mathematics is done with AC assumed.

But we can also consistently assume $\neg$(AC). A set with a countably infinite subset is called Dedekind-infinite. AC (or just DC) implies that every non-finite set is Dedekind-infinite, But it has been shown that it is consistent (with $\neg$AC) that there exists a non-finite set that is not Dedekind-infinite.